# PHP DateTime object's diff() method causing issues with float variables

Tags: php, datetime, floating-point

PHP v 5.3.5

I am having an issue where DateTime->diff seems to be mucking around with variables (which are type float) that it has no business touching. I'm obviously not understanding some way the object works (new to PHP OOP) or variable reference in general. Here's the code, and then I'll explain the output and what's weird.

```
$interval_in_seconds = $settings['interval'] * 86400;
$checkin_in_seconds = floor($checkin['timestamp'] / 1000);
$next_checkin = $checkin_in_seconds + $interval_in_seconds;
$until_next = $next_checkin - time();

if($until_next > 0) {
    $days = floor($until_next / 86400);

    function secondsToTime($seconds) {
        // Only here for var_dump testing:
        global $settings, $interval_in_seconds, $until_next, $next_checkin;

        $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
        $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");

var_dump($until_next);
        $return = $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
var_dump($until_next);

        return $return;
    }
    $countdown = $days . ' days, ' . secondsToTime($until_next);
}
```

`$settings['interval']` is equal to 12 and is a float.
`$checkin['timestamp']` is 1413926734544 and a string (came from JS, hence the milliseconds)

Most of the time, but not all, $settings['interval'] or any of the other variables that I'm pulling in for debugging with `global` will display the correct value for the first `var_dump()` but a random character for the second one *after* the `$dtF->diff($dtT)`

Usually that character is < or ~, but I've also gotten 0 or one of the ascii crosses. I think that is dependent on which variable I'm dumping.

Example output for `$settings['interval']`

```
float(12) float(<)
```

The value returned from that function is correct and works as excepted, however, one of my other variables is getting taken into a dark alley and beaten up. I cannot figure out why. None of those variables are being manipulated, nothing (seems) to be passed by reference, and this was the case even before I used `global`

What's going on here?

Comment: I really don't know, but try this and see what happens: `$checkin_in_seconds = floor((float)$checkin['timestamp'] / 1000);`

Comment: http://ideone.com/a2ETjU -- is the outcome wrong here?

Comment: Why are you getting a JavaScript String for part of your date from PHP? If you want the Client Time use JavaScript. If you want the Server Time use PHP.

Comment: @zerkms That looks to be working correctly, however on my (local) server it is not reliably repeatable. Did you change anything aside from adding in the missing variable values?

Comment: @PHPglue Adding in the (float) didn't help. The reason for the JS timestamp is because earlier in the program, the client POSTs a timestamp for storage. I suppose I could have made the change to seconds prior to that, but at this point have decided to keep the most accurate data stored and manipulate it on the way out.

Comment: @Philip: I copied your exact code. You could do that yourself to check (before you asked). And as we have found that it's localized to your machine - it makes sense for you to spend a minute or two and localize an exact expression that behaves differently.

Comment: @zerkms I wasn't aware there were places you could test PHP code like ideone.com I'm sure that's locked down somehow so I'm not sure how much the implementation will be the same. But you make a good point and show that it's probably a local issue. I've pushed the dev code to the production server and it seems to be working. Now I'm wondering what's screwed up on my box.

Thanks for the help. I tried to do my due diligence of researching and prepping the question, fwiw...

Comment: @Philip: so you are saying that, if you run this code, **ONLY this code** (like zerkms demonstrated on that link), on your server, you get different results?